# Error deploying rails 4 app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm relatively new to using rails and I'm having a problem with deploying my app to Heroku. I've been developing on cloud 9 and when I push to Heroku the deploy seems to go fine but when I visit the page I get an error message.

The heroku Logs show:

```
> 2015-08-01T00:40:57.837873+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
2015-08-01T00:40:58.556903+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-01T00:40:58.536297+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-08-01T06:17:19.117796+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-08-01T06:17:23.307569+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 52477 -e production`
2015-08-01T06:17:24.882803+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
2015-08-01T06:17:25.734232+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-08-01T06:17:25.747443+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-01T11:53:45.697762+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-08-01T11:53:50.557525+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 10565 -e production`
2015-08-01T11:53:51.908604+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
2015-08-01T11:53:52.785739+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-08-01T11:53:52.800814+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-01T14:41:40.344671+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-08-01T14:41:40.344696+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-08-01T14:41:40.288575+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 0b99a6d by siansapp@gmail.com
2015-08-01T14:41:40.288575+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v15 created by siansapp@gmail.com
2015-08-01T14:41:40.679507+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-08-01T14:41:45.306418+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 8728 -e production`
2015-08-01T14:41:47.429945+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
2015-08-01T14:41:48.366370+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-08-01T14:41:48.378255+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-01T14:41:48.378255+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-08-01T14:41:57.271432+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 13560 -e production`
2015-08-01T14:41:59.763596+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
2015-08-01T14:42:00.751968+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-01T14:42:00.692217+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-08-01T15:26:56.794786+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-08-01T15:27:01.996396+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 24984 -e production`
2015-08-01T15:27:04.117927+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
2015-08-01T15:27:05.076538+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-01T15:27:05.065908+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-08-01T16:18:08.915947+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-08-01T16:18:13.350621+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 40930 -e production`
2015-08-01T16:18:15.489473+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
2015-08-01T16:18:16.308171+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-08-01T16:18:16.330662+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-01T18:03:47.083386+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-08-01T18:03:51.426448+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 12413 -e production`
2015-08-01T18:03:53.202502+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
2015-08-01T18:03:54.025103+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-08-01T18:03:54.049376+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-01T20:31:29.290114+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/?_c9_id=livepreview0&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io" host=jump-start-app.herokuapp.com request_id=b94c555a-8552-49ef-98d4-e992c4b7f37a fwd="213.233.148.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-01T20:31:31.068880+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/?_c9_id=livepreview0&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io" host=jump-start-app.herokuapp.com request_id=17e02081-6b91-4125-810a-75fd7553717b fwd="213.233.148.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-01T20:31:31.559148+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=jump-start-app.herokuapp.com request_id=9f1735da-4e59-48cd-bc7a-6c2972fdc74a fwd="213.233.148.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-01T20:38:59.452899+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/?_c9_id=livepreview0&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io" host=jump-start-app.herokuapp.com request_id=56246be2-0ed6-4341-9bdb-c09503ef574e fwd="213.233.148.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-01T20:38:59.922565+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=jump-start-app.herokuapp.com request_id=0da233c6-1dd4-4cab-ae1a-bd660e5a3b4c fwd="213.233.148.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-01T20:40:43.146796+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/?_c9_id=livepreview0&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io" host=jump-start-app.herokuapp.com request_id=89eb8e2b-0065-4d5f-bedf-619cfe1a7448 fwd="213.233.148.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-01T20:40:43.592172+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=jump-start-app.herokuapp.com request_id=13b4580c-7d73-4557-ab70-bee7c9694c67 fwd="213.233.148.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-01T21:10:41.735259+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-08-01T21:10:46.688534+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 38883 -e production`
2015-08-01T21:10:48.844712+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
2015-08-01T21:10:49.790883+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-01T21:10:49.771420+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-08-01T21:14:33.052844+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bash` by siansapp@gmail.com
2015-08-01T21:14:41.082824+00:00 heroku[run.5556]: Starting process with command `bash`
2015-08-01T21:14:41.028523+00:00 heroku[run.5556]: Awaiting client
2015-08-01T21:14:41.485121+00:00 heroku[run.5556]: State changed from starting to up
2015-08-01T21:14:43.502980+00:00 heroku[run.5556]: Process exited with status 127
2015-08-01T21:14:43.511383+00:00 heroku[run.5556]: State changed from up to complete
2015-08-01T21:45:49.793767+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy fbedf97 by siansapp@gmail.com
2015-08-01T21:45:49.793767+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v16 created by siansapp@gmail.com
2015-08-01T21:45:49.851010+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-08-01T21:45:49.851031+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-08-01T21:45:50.004462+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-08-01T21:45:54.795134+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 47602 -e production`
2015-08-01T21:45:56.708360+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
2015-08-01T21:45:57.601818+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-08-01T21:45:57.618731+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-01T21:45:57.619677+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-08-01T21:46:03.819972+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 53934 -e production`
2015-08-01T21:46:05.753194+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
2015-08-01T21:46:06.667354+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-01T21:46:06.654482+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-08-01T21:55:10.297772+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy a4b04cd by siansapp@gmail.com
2015-08-01T21:55:10.297772+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v17 created by siansapp@gmail.com
2015-08-01T21:55:10.377020+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-08-01T21:55:10.377040+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-08-01T21:55:11.095268+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-08-01T21:55:17.864626+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2015-08-01T21:55:19.872652+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bundle: command not found
2015-08-01T21:55:20.725657+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-01T21:55:20.706419+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-08-01T21:55:23.296769+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=jump-start-app.herokuapp.com request_id=d3b63340-8bea-4f1b-b682-542cd03a6ff3 fwd="213.233.148.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-01T21:55:23.641812+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=jump-start-app.herokuapp.com request_id=1b7b38b2-1a63-4738-bb11-743b0a542a62 fwd="213.233.148.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-01T21:57:03.013725+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 91324fa by siansapp@gmail.com
2015-08-01T21:57:03.013725+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v18 created by siansapp@gmail.com
2015-08-01T21:57:03.077639+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-08-01T21:57:03.077656+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-08-01T21:57:03.900413+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-08-01T21:57:11.881058+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 19971 -e production`
2015-08-01T21:57:14.685026+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
2015-08-01T21:57:15.586421+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-08-01T21:57:15.602383+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-01T21:57:15.603603+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-08-01T21:57:19.020926+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 16821 -e production`
2015-08-01T21:57:20.510190+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
2015-08-01T21:57:21.248670+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-08-01T21:57:21.267300+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-01T21:57:22.437971+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=jump-start-app.herokuapp.com request_id=5ac6c7ec-1573-4682-8578-0ab7922e74c6 fwd="213.233.148.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-01T21:57:23.227534+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=jump-start-app.herokuapp.com request_id=17bfa86d-e75c-49ac-b373-20b81e0eb1ba fwd="213.233.148.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
WARNING: Toolbelt v3.40.6 update available.
```

I've looked at other answers to the  "/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory" error but I think the files in my bin are fine:

Bundle:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
load Gem.bin_path('bundler', 'bundle')
```

Rails:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

Rake:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rake'
Rake.application.run
```

I've tried updating my bin anyway but that didn't help. I'm not sure what else to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you installed "gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production"
and defined your ruby version in gemfile?

Comment: Yup, I've got them in a production group in the Gemfile and I've declared Ruby version 2.2.1. If it helps my repository can be found here: https://github.com/sian-nadin/exercise. I'm just looking into testing at the moment in case I just have some loosely coupled relationships that might be causing the error.

Comment: I have tried to push your app on a my heroku, and i don't have problem... i have only some problem with postgree, but not in the deploy...  here a copy of my console: https://gist.github.com/pierangelo1982/cb02cf50f9db8811670d

Comment: I get the same thing when I deploy my app, it looks like everything worked but when I try to access it using 'heroku open' I get "Opening jump-start-app... xprop:  unable to open display ''
xprop:  unable to open display ''
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'https://jump-start-app.herokuapp.com/'
done".

Answer (score 0):

Had just this error, it drove me crazy for two days.  Finally found it was due to bundling my rails app on Windows. If this is your case delete the `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle`on an Unix OS.  Then commit and deploy to Heroku.

Other symptoms: `bundle`, `rails`, and `rake` commands all returned => 
`: No such file or directory00:00 app[worker.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby`